# How do I troubleshoot when voting isn't working?

Tags: support, voting, javascript, web-sockets, troubleshooting

Today, I can't vote, at least on Travel.se and possibly on other sites. Sometimes, I get the red "an error occurred, please retry" message and sometimes it appears to work but if I load the page again, the post score has gone back down and there is no indication I voted.

Normally, I reload the page, maybe Ctrl-F5, and everything is fine. But that's not happening today. I have no idea what my next step would be. Does anyone?

Comment: needs a tag about the ajax or the javascript or the postback or whatnot, but the tag-suggesty stuff is broken too, and I can't edit either. Sigh.

Comment: Next step would be to make sure Javascript is loading. Are you running HTTPS Everywhere, by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so, @AnnaLear, but when it comes to sysadmin stuff I'm a great developer :-). Also the inbox notify is working

Comment: It's happier now, but the question remains: when it's not happy, and F5 isn't cutting it, is there any other way to figure out where stuff is going wrong?

Comment: seems to be related to flaky wifi at a group event - when everyone starts hammering the wifi I can't vote, edit etc for a while

Comment: Are you using a different browser than usual?

Comment: no, but different wifi than usual

Comment: As an aside: why do you think voting uses WebSockets? (Ajax/XHR, yes. Sockets, no, *I'd think*.)

Comment: I think displaying an accurate vote count (including knowing that mine didn't stick) uses websockets.